# How do I get the last four weeks including current week using an sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch last 4 weeks results including this week. so let say i have a stat table which is full of stats of last month April, now its 4 May... when I write this query:
I want to fetch unique visitors:

```
 SELECT COUNT(distinct ip ) AS uni, (
date_added
) AS wday, FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) AS cusotms
FROM  `site_stats` 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) >= DATE_SUB( SYSDATE( ) , INTERVAL 4 WEEK ) 
GROUP BY WEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) )
```

It found following results:

```
uni     wday        cusotms
2   1333819740  2012-04-07 22:29:00
6   1333906140  2012-04-08 22:29:00
7   1334510940  2012-04-15 22:29:00
7   1335115740  2012-04-22 22:29:00
5   1336089600  2012-05-04 05:00:00
```

But I want last 4 weeks including this week. I dont know why this is showing me record of 4 may, 22 april, 15 april and then 8 and 7 april. I was thinking something like below

is this correct result for last 4 weeks group by week? I was thinking it should be something like 4 may,

```
4 may
4-7 = 28 april
4-14days = 21 april
and then 14 april
and last 7 april
??
```

I need to put this output in graph for showing last week stats... Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Last 4 weeks including this week, you get the results you want.

Comment: you mean its correct result? but i am confused that why 7 and 8 april results are coming together? Also, I want name of week as well. such as start day name of each week. i-e: 50 unique : 28April, 40Unique: 21April, 20Unique: 14April ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ip ) AS uni, ( 
    date_added
    ) AS wday, FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) AS cusotms
    FROM `site_stats` 
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -3WEEK
    GROUP BY WEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) ) 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You fetch the exact date, it seems like you want to fetch the week:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ip ) AS uni, (
date_added
) AS wday, WEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added ) ) AS cusotms
```

Comment: Hi Karoly, Thanks for quick reply, Actually I just added last field to show the date because date is stored in db in timestamp format. In shor I just want to fetch unique visits (ip) from my stat table of last 4 weeks. Also I dont know if its possible to add incomplete week with those last week. such as this week plus last 4 weeks?

Comment: the incomplete last week is not an issue but you have to work on it to get the full data for the first week.

Comment: yes and I need help here because I am on it from last 2 days and could not sort, I got working last 7+today and other situations but this is something freaking me out.

Comment: Or at least I want the last 4 weeks correct result, I can skip this week. One thing important is I want it with group by so I will show that in first week I have 50 unique visitors and in second 100 etc... till 4th week.

Comment: I prefer to do this on client side because it's a lot easier, but for some ideas check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313962/php-mysql-retrieving-the-last-full-weeks-entries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week